# Pointers to arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I found an example of a pointer to array which to me doesn't make much sense, I was wondering if anybody would be able to help me?

```
int a[5] = 0,1,4,89,6;
int *p = a;  'p points at the start of a'
p[3] = 1;  'a[3] is now 6'
```

I'm not sure how the third line, p[3] = 1, works and how it causes a[3] = 6. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I think `5[a]` is the same as `a[5]` andI'm right :)

Comment: yea 5[a] is same as a[5] because 5 + a is same as a + 5. But is not what Tarius asks

Comment: Tarius - could you add C or C++ tag (or language you are using because it could be C with Classes or C--)

Comment: @Tarius-Whichever book you're referring to, just throw that crap.

Comment: @Tarius - is it really commented in this way in the book? :)

Comment: Yes, the comment is very wrong.  If the last line were changed to read `p[3] = 1;  /* a[3] is now 1 */` -- which is correct -- would you still have a question?

Comment: Okay that makes complete sense now, I thought it might be wrong but wasn't sure. It was in my lecture notes, so probably just a typo, thanks for all the help.

Comment: @SteveSummit It makes complete sense now, thanks anyway. I understand how pointers work, it's just I thought I was missing something fundamental when I came across that example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bit incorrect. `a[3]` is `1`, not `6`.

Here are explanation line by line:

```
int a[5] = 0,1,4,89,6;
int *p = a;  //'p points at the start of a'
p[3] = 1;  //'a[3] is now 1 not 6'
```

First line initialize the array. I think there should be {} around numbers, but if compiles with you then is OK. This is how I believe it should be:

```
int a[5] = {0,1,4,89,6};
```

Second line create pointer to int `p` and initialize it to the address of `a`. Arrays and pointers are closely related in C, so now, you have 2 variables `a` and `p` pointing to one and same memory address.

Third line - you set `p[3]` to `1`, this time you access `p` as array of int (it is possible because of that relationship between arrays and pointers). Because `p` and `a` points in same memory address, this means `a[3]` is now `1`

Also remarks are incorrect, must be /* */ or //.

**UPDATE** :

David's comment is very important.

Arrays are sequential reserved memory capable to store several array values, in your case 5 int's.

A pointer is a pointer and may point everywhere they can point to int variable:

```
int a = 5;
int *b = &a;
```

or they can point to array as in your case. In both cases you will be able to use [], but in case it points to single value, any array subscript greater than zero will be wrong, e.g.

```
int a = 5;
int *b = &a;
*b = 4;    // OK.
b[0] = 4; // OK.
b[1] = 4; // compiles correctly, but is **wrong**.
          // it will overwrite something in memory
          // and if program not crash,
          // it will be security hole.

int x[10];
int *y = x;
*y = 4;    // works correctly for y[0], 
           // but makes it difficult to read.
y[0] = 5;  // OK
y[9] = 5;  // OK
y[10] = 5; // compiles correctly, but is **wrong**.
           // it is after last element of x.
           // this is called **buffer overflow**.
           // it will overwrite something in memory
           // and if program not crash,
           // it will be security hole.
```

**UPDATE** :

I recommend you check this article
http://boredzo.org/pointers/

Comment: Be careful. A `pointer` and `array` are NOT the same thing in C. An array is a sequential, reserved block of memory, either statically declared on the stack or dynamically allocated on the heap. True, the reference used to point to the first element of the array is a pointer, but not the array itself. On the other hand, `p` above is just a pointer to type `int`. It can be assigned the address to the first element in the array and behave thereafter as a pointer to that array, but that is only due to the fact the compiler knows the type of the pointer so that pointer arithmetic allows the use.

Comment: you are both correct and not correct in same time. you can always do int a = 5; int *b = &a; and then a[1] = 100; this is memory violation, **but** it will be compilled and in some cases will work without visible error. But because is wrong practice, I am giving you +1.

Comment: You're getting there, but please  delete the sentence "Arrays and pointers are one and same thing in C" which is very, very false, and please don't say "so now, you have 2 arrays a and p", because what we have here is one array `a` and one pointer `p`.

Comment: `y = 4;` is wrong. The same goes for `b = 4;`. In both the cases, you are assigning an `int*` with an `int`.